# Google Glass Software Version: XE18.3 update issue

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

After updating to XE 18.3 (Jul 1, 2014) Glass is getting hot so quickly. I cant video more than 3/4 mins or run any apps around 6/8 min. Any one face that? I used glass since XE12 - December 17, 2013 and never faced that problem. I could video around 10 min or play games around 15/20 mins before last update.

Any suggestions/solutions? Please.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get support on product related issue is to contact your guide (Support tab on MyGlass).